# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: winforms, datagridview

C# Winforms Solution - Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition.

Hello, everyone!  When I debug my application, open my form, click on the comboBoxCurso (parent comboBox) and select English, for example, then click on the comboBoxModulo (child comboBox) in the DataGridView, I get an error saying:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: It's not possible to find the column [English]."

```
    private void Alunos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

      this.tbl_cursosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_cursos);

      this.tbl_modulosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_modulos);

      this.tbl_turmasTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_turmas);

      this.tbl_alunosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_alunos);

      this.tbl_alunos_subTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_alunos_sub);



      DataView dv = new DataView(bremingtonDataSet.Tables["tbl_modulos"]);

      filteredModulosBS.DataSource = dv;

 }





    private void tbl_alunos_subDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == comboBoxModulo.Index)

        {

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

            dgcb.DataSource = filteredModulosBS;

            **Error =====> this.filteredModulosBS.Filter = "Código = "+ this.tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); <===== Error**


        }

    }





    private void tbl_alunos_subDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.comboBoxModulo.Index)

        {

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

            dgcb.DataSource = tblmodulosBindingSource;

            this.filteredModulosBS.RemoveFilter();

        }

    }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this line of code?  Thank you very much for your time and help.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the filter condition argument in single quotes `'`.

```
this.filteredModulosBS.Filter = "Código = '" + this.tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "'";
```

Comment: Hi there,  Thank you for replying.  I tried your line of code and I'm now getting an error when I click on the second comboBox:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Not possible to do the operation '=' in System.Int32 and System.String.**

Comment: I assumed that the column `Código` is a `String` type based on your description of "select English" and the error message you recieved.  Based on the current error, I have to assume that `Código` is a `System.Int32`.  Please edit your question and tell us what data type `Código` is and what `this.tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex].Value` contains.

Comment: Ok, here we go:  **Código** is a primary key for the Module (Modulo) in the table tbl_modulos.
**this.tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex].Value**
contains the the list of Cursos (Courses) offered by the school.

Comment: @JCCarmo, you need to think about this filter you are creating.  It may help if you create an intermediate `string` variable to assign to the bindingsource filter property and set a breakpoint so that you can inspect the result.  Does it make sense that Código will be equal to the specified value?  I am making many guesses as to what filter value is, but based on the errors you are reporting it is:  `Código='English'`.  However, the current error is telling you that it cannot compare an Int32 to a String, so  Código is evidently an integer.  Perhaps, you meant a different column?

Comment: I've tried different columns too, but it still gives me an error message saying it cannot find the column...